# Using JDK1.6.0_131 with SHA-256 Algorithm

Tags: java

I use JDK1.6.0_131 to sign a Jar file with SHA-256 as below.

jarsigner -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -tsadigestalg SHA-256 -tsa http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp -keystore mykeystore MyApplet.jar cert

The error message shown is:

jarsigner: unable to sign jar: sun.security.pkcs.ParsingException: Unable to parse the encoded bytes

There is no such problem when using JDK1.7 or JDK1.8. What is the most likely cause of this error? Thanks.

SK

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and according to this:
https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=SO15502

I had  to use the legacy sha1 :
Note: For legacy SHA-1 timestamping, please use the SHA-1 RFC 3161 timestamping URL: http://sha1timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha1/timestamp

Signing the jars with this for 1.6 worked.